# Laptop will POST but not fully boot, reading too much RAM?

Tags: windows-7, boot, memory, motherboard, bios

I'm currently 'furbishing an HP 630 laptop running Windows 7 Pro Service Pack 1. It has two slots for RAM and uses type DD3L-128000S. Documentation states a maximum of 8 gigabytes supported, which should not be exceeded. It came with a 4gb stick and I put in another 8gb stick which I hoped would read as a 4gb module instead. 
Now it won't finish booting and system information says it can see all 12 gigabytes installed.

My Query; Is there a way to: 
A. Tweak the BIOS, MoBo or other settings to boot with all 12 gigs? 
B: Dumb it down so it can only read half the module and use 4gb? 
C: Take out the 4gb stick and use a single 8gb?

If it helps: Trying to boot up using only the 8gb module resulted in a BSOD of the Bad Pool Header variety. Trying to boot with both results in the Windows or Startup Menu appearing for a brief period of time followed by the laptop restarting.

Comment: Firstly, remove the 4Gb, it's not going to boot if you're exceeding the specified limit. However, are you sure the 8Gb stick is good? It maybe worth seeing if you can boot up memtest to test it. https://www.memtest86.com/

Comment: (am I doing this right?) Using just the 8gb stick caused a BSOD. I tried starting memtest with all 12gb inside, but no such luck. I'm afraid I lack a laptop that can utilize the 8gb stick so I'm not sure how Id test it.

Comment: Your laptop won't support anything over 8Gb, so take the 4Gb stick out, then test the 8Gb on it's own.

Comment: It looks like it's a max of 4GB per slot for a total max of 8GB. Do you have another 4GB stick lying around? https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02822368#AbT4

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a max of 4GB per slot for a total max of 8GB. Do you have another 4GB stick lying around?

support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02822368#AbT4